# Receiving client data using nodejs tcp server

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to receive data from a client that is sending data to my server. This is my code that inserts the incoming data into msql

```
var net = require('net');
var mysql = require('mysql');
var randomstring = require("randomstring");

var server = net.createServer(function(socket) {
    socket.write('Echo server\r\n');
    socket.pipe(socket);
});
 socket.on('data', function (data) {

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : 'seizedserver.com',
  user     : 'federal',
  password : '123456',
  database : 'hanging_tree'
});

connection.connect();
/*
connection.query('SELECT data from gps', function(err, rows) {
  if (err) throw err;

  console.log('The solution is: ', rows[0]);
});
*/
var post  = {data: data};
var query = connection.query('INSERT INTO gps SET ?', post, function(err, result) {
});
console.log(query.sql); 

connection.end();
  });
server.listen(1337, '127.0.0.1');
```

The plan is to insert incoming data into the mysql table i have created but i am not sure i am using the data event correctly.

Am i using the data event correctly?.

I get this error when i run my script with forever

```
/var/www/html/server.js:9
 socket.on('data', function (data) {
 ^
ReferenceError: socket is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/html/server.js:9:2)
    at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:902:3
error: Forever detected script exited with code: 8
```

Comment: Why to use socket instead route? Are you using some framework (Express, etc)?

Comment: Well, the error says it all - `socket.on` is being used outside of the scope where it has been defined.

Comment: I require an example on where socket starts and ends. That's what's giving me trouble.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`socket` is only defined in the callback of your server:

```
var server = net.createServer(function(socket) {
    socket.write('Echo server\r\n');
    socket.pipe(socket);
});

 // socket is undefined here
 socket.on('data', function (data) {

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host     : 'seizedserver.com',
  user     : 'federal',
  password : '123456',
  database : 'hanging_tree'
});
```

Should be:

```
var server = net.createServer(function(socket) {
    socket.write('Echo server\r\n');

    // socket is defined here and in scope
    socket.on('data', function (data) {

    var connection = mysql.createConnection({
      host     : 'seizedserver.com',
      user     : 'federal',
      password : '123456',
      database : 'hanging_tree'
    });

    socket.pipe(socket);
});
```